# How can I access my folders?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, shared-folders

I have been using my desktop for several months successfully dual-booting between Kubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. Recently, Windows planted a major upgrade which required several reboots, and which I suspect is responsible for the problem I now have, which is that, in Kubuntu I usually cannot access the data folders which are also accessed by Windows (which is almost all of them). I never had the problem before the recent upgrade, and I have once successfully used Kubuntu since, so the problem may be due to something else. Error message stated that there was a mounting error:  Shutting down no longer works

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: post the error message

Comment: the update turned "Fast Startup" on. the shared folders are hibernated. Open Windows and turn "Fast Startup" off.

Comment: Thanks wjandrea, I added the error message but it somwhow got lost  - I no longer see it. Thanks, too, ravery, this seems to have solved the problem

Comment: Thanks wjandrea, I tried to add the message to my original post but it got deleted; I no longer see it. Thanks ravery, this seems to have solved the issue; I dont see how to accept and vote up your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/301745) - though maybe there's a more specific one related to updates resetting the "Fast Startup" setting.